# Porting OpenGL ES Framebuffer to OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3

I got the following code working perfectly fine on iOS and Android:

```
unsigned int depth_texture = 0,
             framebuffer = 0;

glGenTextures( 1, &depth_texture );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture );

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
              0,
              GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
              256,
              256,
              0,
              GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
              GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
              NULL );

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

glGenFramebuffers( 1, &framebuffer );

glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );

glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                        GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                        depth_texture,
                        0 );

unsigned int type = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );

if( type == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE )
{ printf( "Complete!" ); }
else
{ printf( "Error!" ); }
```

Now I'm porting this code to OpenGL Desktop (2.1 and up) and it refuses to work. I always get the error `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER`. The only way I found to make it work is to specify a COLOR_ATTACHMENT (which would fix the draw buffer error). I read the GL glFrameBuffer docs, and I cannot comprehend why the code above wouldn't work. All I want to is to render ONLY the depth into a texture... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to render to any color buffers, you need a call that specifies that:

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

This is per framebuffer state, so it needs to be called while the FBO is bound.

If you miss this, you will get the error you're seeing, as specified for the error conditions under "Framebuffer Completeness" in the OpenGL 3.3 spec:

> The value of FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE must not be NONE for any color attachment point(s) named by DRAW_BUFFERi.
>
> {FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER}

The default draw buffer for FBOs is `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, so this error condition applies if you don't have an attachment for `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, and leave the draw buffer at the default.

To avoid the very similar `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER` error condition, you will also need to set the read buffer to `GL_NONE`:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

These error conditions are **not** listed in **any** OpenGL ES spec, as far as I could find. So the `glDrawBuffer()` call is not needed there.

It gets stranger still: Checking all the desktop OpenGL specs starting at 3.0, where FBOs were introduced, the error condition is listed in the specs for 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, and 4.0. It was not in 3.0, and even more interestingly, it is **gone** in 4.1 and later. As pointed out by @derhass in a comment, this was part of the [ARB_ES2_compatibility](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES2_compatibility.txt) extension that became core in OpenGL 4.1.

Memorize this, and you can show off at the next OpenGL trivia night. If there is such a thing. :)

Comment: a dumb question - `FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE` for color attachments must not be none for completeness. And `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` sets it to none? Or does `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` has different meaning

Comment: Sort of, but not quite. In your case, `FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE` is NONE for all color attachment points because you don't have any color attachments. But based on the default for the draw buffer, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` would be "named by DRAW_BUFFERi". So the corresponding attachment "must not be NONE", but it is. Therefore, error!

Comment: As for why this is gone in 4.1: This comes via [GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES2_compatibility.txt): "Remove all references to draw/read buffers affecting completeness", also adding "If the GL is bound to a framebuffer object and a draw buffer selects an attachment that has no image attached, then that fragment color is not written to any buffer."

Comment: I also needed to add glReadBuffer( GL_NONE ); in order to make it work on my card.

Comment: @derhass Excellent, makes sense now. That didn't even cross my mind when I tried to find an explanation yesterday. I added a sentence about it to the answer.